# Android:Custom Fonts to Text View. It mess up my other code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts, android-typeface

I was able to change the font in a new fresh project (only one activity and text "hello world") in Android Studio to a unique font not available in Android Studio. It worked great.

But when I followed the exact same procedure and used the exact same code in my existing project it worked too BUT it messed up my other java code in the activity.

Specifically, the Activity On Button Click via Intent. Clicking on the button did not open the new activity anymore.

I removed the java code for the custom font because priority is for the button intent to work.  I am a complete amateur and have only been doing development in android for 6 weeks (no prior coding experience).

Below you can see the code. You can see below I placed the code in the exact same place in both the fresh project and existing project. What do I need to do to get the custom font AND have the button intent work in the existing project?

**FRESH PROJECT**

```
package com.example.android.practice2;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset (getAssets(),"font.ttf"); 
        TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview99);
        myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

    }
}
```

**EXISTING PROJECT:**

Where do I place the code here? 
Placed where it is now creates a custom font but the button intent stops working?

```
    package com.example.android.xxxxxx;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        /* Below for button to open new activity */
        private static Button button_sbm;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            OnClickButtonListener();
Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
        TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview99);
        myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

        }

        /*  Opens 3rd Activity  */
        public void OnClickButtonListener() {
            button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
            button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.yes.FirstActivity");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
            );

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to this code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button_sbm;
private TextView myTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview99);

    Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
    myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    button_sbm.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click is Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.yes.FirstActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```